# running external program and obtaining returned integer

Tags: c++, system, return

I have the following MWE, which returns an integer:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = 2;
    return a;
}
```

Now I want to call this program via the command line (cmd) in Windows. Here is a program for how I do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a = system("c:\test_batch.exe");
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

However this does not return the value 2, but 0. I don't understand this as I thought system() returned  the exit-code of the program, in this case 2.

Comment: Search for IPC - inter process communication.

Answer (score 1):

system returns a value returned by a command interpeter, not by actual command.

you need to do something like

```
int a = system("c:\test_batch.exe && exit %ERRORLEVEL%");
```